# python and process

Tags: python, windows, wmi

What is the best way in python find the process name and owner?

Now i use WMI, but this version is too slow.

Answer (score 1):

By using https://github.com/giampaolo/psutil:

```
>>> import psutil, os
>>> p = psutil.Process(os.getpid())
>>> p.name()
'python.exe'
>>> p.username()
'giampaolo'
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Process name: is sys.argv[0] not sufficient for your purposes?